# regular expression with the same element twice without knowing it

Tags: regex, grep, emacs23

I've plenty fill and want to find all of them which are like this:

```
A = A + B
```

So I wanna use a regular expression using `M + x rgrep`. and was thinking to something like that: `([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*) = () + [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*` where `()` create a group which can be used latter.

Their is a way to make a regular expression where two item must be the same but without knowing the form of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*) = \1 \+ [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eJ9fY2/6)

Comment: It's the behavior I want. But when I try it with emacs or in tty, I have an error: `grep: invalid back reference`

Comment: Back reference may differ for languages. It would be `\1` or `$1` or `#1`

Comment: For grep it's $1. Perfect. Thank you `:)`